# Not able to archive all the data

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, c++14

I am using boost for serialization of data.

This is how the classes are structured.

1) I have a Stage class
This class holds vector data for the director class

```
class Stage
{
public:
    std::vector<Director> directors;
    void AddDirector(Director dir) { directors.push_back(dir); }
    int GetDirectorSize() { return directors.size(); }
    Director* GetDirector(int number) { return &directors[number]; }

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<typename Archive>
    void save(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) const {
        ar & directors;
    }
    template<typename Archive>
    void load(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & directors;
    }
    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
};
```

2) This is the director class
This class holds vector data of weak pointers for the channel class.

```
class Director
{
public:
    std::string stdstrName;
    std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Channel>> channels;
    Director() { stdstrName = "NO_NAME"; }
    void SetName(std::string name) { stdstrName = name; }
    std::string GetName() { return stdstrName; }
    void AddChannel(std::weak_ptr<Channel> chn) { channels.push_back(chn); }
    std::shared_ptr<Channel> GetChannel(int number) { return channels[number].lock(); }
    int GetChannelSize() {return channels.size();}
    std::string GetChannelType( int number){
        if (std::shared_ptr<Channel> chn = channels[number].lock())
            return chn->GetChannelType();   
    }

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<typename Archive>
    void save(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) const {
        ar & stdstrName & channels;
    }
    template<typename Archive>
    void load(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & stdstrName & channels;
    }
    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()

};
```

3) This is the channel class

Channel class needs to know about the container where it is created and the 
director where this is stored as a Weak_pointer

1) This class holds a pointer to the Director object.

2) This class holds a pointer to the Container object.

```
class Container;
class Director;

class Channel
{
public:
    Director* dir;
    Container* cont;
    std::string stdstrChannelType;
    Channel() { stdstrChannelType = "NO_TYPE"; }
    Channel(std::string type): stdstrChannelType(type){  }
    void SetDirector(Director* director);
    void SetContainer(Container* container);
    std::string GetChannelType() { return  stdstrChannelType;}
    Director* GetDirector() { return dir; }

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<typename Archive>
    void save(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) const {
        ar & dir & cont & stdstrChannelType;
    }
    template<typename Archive>
    void load(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & dir & cont & stdstrChannelType;
    }
    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()

};
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
 #include "Channel.h"
#include <vector>

class PositionChannel : public Channel
{
public:
    std::vector<int> keyframes;
    PositionChannel() : Channel("POSITION") , keyframes( { 1 , 2, 3 }) {    }

   private:
   friend class boost::serialization::access;

typedef Channel _Super;
template<typename Archive>
void save(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) const {
    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<_Super>(*this);
    ar & keyframes;
}
template<typename Archive>
void load(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
    ar & keyframes;
}
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
```

};

4) This is the Container class

1) This is where the Channel is created and saved as a Shared_pointer.

2) The same channel is also saved in the Director class as Weak_Pointer

```
class Container
{
public:
    std::string stdstrName;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Channel>> channel;
    Container() { stdstrName = "cont"; };
    void AddChannel(std::shared_ptr<Channel> chn) 
    { 
        channel.push_back(chn); 
        Director* dir = chn->GetDirector();  // Add the channel to director also
        dir->AddChannel(chn);
    }

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<typename Archive>
    void save(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) const {
        ar & stdstrName & channel;
    }
    template<typename Archive>
    void load(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & stdstrName & channel;
    }
    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()

};
```

Now when i serialize my data and than serialize it the Director is not able to serialize the weak_pointer.

```
Stage stage;
Director dir;
Container cont;
dir.SetName("MAIN");
stage.AddDirector(dir); // Add director to stage
std::shared_ptr<PositionChannel> chn = std::make_shared<PositionChannel>(PositionChannel()); // create a position channel
chn->SetDirector(&dir); // Link the director to channel
chn->SetContainer(&cont); // Link the container to the channel
cont.AddChannel(chn);   // add the channel to the container
std::cout << dir.GetChannelSize() << std::endl; // this gives a value of 1 which is correct
std::ofstream ofs("D://abc.dat");
{
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    // write class instance to archive
    oa << stage <<  cont;  // since director is a data element of stage so it should get serialized
}
Stage stage1;
Container cont1;
{
    // create and open an archive for input
    std::ifstream ifs("D://abc.dat");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    // read class state from archive
    ia >> stage1 >> cont1;

}
std::cout << stage1.GetDirectorSize(); // stage has got the director
Director* dir1 = stage1.GetDirector(0);
std::cout << dir1->GetName(); // the director has the correct name
std::cout << dir1->GetChannelSize(); // it should show 1 as the channel size but i am getting 0
```

Comment: What is the question? "the Director is not able to serialize the weak_pointer" - does that mean it doesn't compile? It do what you expect? What happens?

Comment: @sehe i have overcomplicated this question please have a look at my new question , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62367775/why-the-serialized-pointer-is-not-pointing-at-the-correct-object

Comment: I agree you overcomplicated it. Not the question, but the code. Maybe you should be using simple owned objects, and making relations using separate sets/maps. I feel you can probably model this without a single shared pointer or cyclic dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
stage.AddDirector(dir); // Add director to stage
```

It adds **a copy** of `dir` to the stage::directors` vector.

Later you do

```
chn->SetDirector(&dir); // Link the director to channel
```

This means you point the the variable in `main`. Which was different from the one pushed into the stage. This is likely not what you wanted.

#### Comparing:

```
chn->cont = &cont;
```

sets a pointer to `cont`, which is **also** just a variable in the scope of `main`. The big difference is that that exact object IS serialized into the archive, so if the archive finds pointers pointing to it it can make the link correctly.

### Pointer Conflict

When an object is first deserialized through a pointer it can no longer be deserialized through a reference (because the pointed-to object has already been dynamically allocated).

See for more background inforation: http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/cpp-boost-ser-conflict.html

In your case you have so many cyclic dependencies going on, there is no order in which you can serialize `stage` and `cont` so it doesn't lead to pointer conflict.

The easiest way to break the problem is to make `vector<Director>` into `vector<shared_ptr<Director> >`. Then you still have to make sure that `cont` is serialized before `stage`.

### Fixed Demo

Here's a simplified demo that works:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81b62b204f819951)**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/weak_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <fstream>

namespace Lib {
    struct Container;
    struct Director;

    struct Channel {
        Director* dir = nullptr;
        Container* cont = nullptr;
        virtual ~Channel() = default;
    };
    struct PositionChannel : Channel {
        std::vector<int> keyframes;
    };
    struct Director {
        std::string name;
        std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Channel>> channels;
    };
    struct Stage {
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Director> > directors;
    };
    struct Container {
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Channel> > channels;
    };

    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, Channel& o, unsigned) {
        //ar & o.dir & o.cont; // avoid pointer conflict
        ar & o.cont & o.dir;
    }
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, PositionChannel& o, unsigned) {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Channel>(o)
           & o.keyframes;
    }
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, Director& o, unsigned) {
        ar & o.name & o.channels;
    }
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, Stage& o, unsigned) {
        ar & o.directors;
    }
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, Container& o, unsigned) {
        ar & o.channels;
    }
}

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Lib::Channel)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Lib::PositionChannel)

int main() {
    using namespace Lib;
    {
        Stage stage;
        Container cont;

        auto dir = std::make_shared<Director>();
        dir->name = "MAIN";
        stage.directors.push_back(dir); // Add director to stage

        auto chn = std::make_shared<PositionChannel>(PositionChannel()); // create a position channel
        chn->dir = dir.get();
        chn->cont = &cont;

        dir->channels.emplace_back(chn); // add the weak ptr

        cont.channels.insert(cont.channels.end(),
            { 
                chn,
                std::make_shared<PositionChannel>(),
                std::make_shared<PositionChannel>(),
                std::make_shared<PositionChannel>(),
            });

        {
            std::ofstream ofs("abc.dat");
            boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
            //oa << stage << cont;
            oa << cont << stage;
        }
    }

    {
        std::ifstream ifs("abc.dat");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        Stage stage;
        Container cont;

        //ia >> stage >> cont;
        ia >> cont >> stage;

        assert(cont.channels.size() == 4);

        auto chn = cont.channels.front();
        assert(chn == chn->dir->channels.front().lock());
        assert(chn->cont == &cont);
    }
}
```

Which passes all the asserts and writes a text archive containing:

```
22 serialization::archive 17 1 0
0 0 0 4 1 0 1 4 20 Lib::PositionChannel 1 0
1 1 0
2 0 0 5 1 0
3 4 MAIN 0 0 1 0 0 0 4 1 0 0 4
4
5 -1 -1 0 0 4
6
7 -1 -1 0 0 4
8
9 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 5 3
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer , i understand it was a lengthy question , thank you again for your valueable time.

Comment: No problem. I learned something myself again (the section about pointer conflict). I'd seriously consider simplifying the approach. In case you like, we can have a chat about that sometime.

Comment: sure it would be my pleasure.

Comment: Please let me know when can we have a chat.

Comment: @Summit we can start here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215943/summit-sehe